# Надо сделать программу, которая при нажатии какой-то кнопки будет показывать в окне текст. Где ошибка?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import tkinter as tk
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Введите домашний адрес")
frm_form = tk.Frame(relief=tk.SUNKEN, borderwidth=3)
frm_form.pack()
que = tk.Label(master=frm_form, text="Ответ: ")
ans= tk.Entry(master=frm_form, width=50)
def end():
    end=tk.Label(master=frm_form, text='True!')
but=tk.Button(text='check', command=end)
but.pack()
que.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="e")
ans.grid(row=0, column=1)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: @Интик, как название переменной для объекта Tk влияет на написание многооконных программ?

Comment: чтоб не путать окна. но если ваш опыт показывает обратное, то извиняюсь.

Comment: @Интик 1 - лучше не называть объекты окон просто window, а называть по их назначению. Главное окно (которое обычно называют root) имеет смысл назвать main_window. 2 - многооконные проекты имеет смысл структурировать - разбивать на классы и модули. При разбивке на модули дочерние окна вообще не будут видеть как там называется переменная главного окна, потому что она вообще в другом модуле находится.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы виджет появился в окне, его нужно не только создать, но и разместить (в данном случае с помощью `grid`):

```
def end():
    tk.Label(master=frm_form, text='True!').grid()

but=tk.Button(text='check', command=end)
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!!! Работает!

Comment: @CATpython, если ответ помог, вы можете отметить его принятым - поставить галку слева от ответа.